# Asp.Net C# How to pass null value parameter to datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a gridview with a parameter. It is bound to a datasource which is a SQL query. The query returns rows when executed in SQL Server when the value of the parameter is null. When I try to pass the parameter a null value via the following line of code I get no results.

```
FormDS.SelectParameters["ServiceFormCompletedId"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["sfcId"];
```

The querystring does not exist so it passes a null value to the FormDS Datasource. The SelectParameters said it was a null value.

So I tried giving it an empty string.

```
FormDS.SelectParameters["ServiceFormCompletedId"].DefaultValue = "";
```

with the following in the markup of ASP.NET

```
<asp:Parameter Name="ServiceFormCompletedId" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```

There was also no results.

I tested the Datasource with the following values in the Test Query section of the Configure Data Source and got rows back.

[image: enter image Configure Data Source]

What am I missing about passing null values to the SelectParameters of a SqlDataSource?

Comment: Have you tried DbNull.Value ?

Comment: How to I use DbNull ? I just tried it. Can not implicity convert type 'System.DBNull' to a 'string'. I tried DbNull.ToString and that does not work as it is an empty string and that is not working.

Comment: The answer can be found here : [Stack Overflow : pass null value to DB via sqldatasource.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858769/aspcontrolparameter-pass-null-value-to-db-via-sqldatasource)

Comment: Maybe You can use ternary if the string is empty / the length is 0, pass DBNull.Value, otherwise, pass your string.

Comment: @WazeAndroid is correct. The previous solution worked well. I initially ignored it as I could not see it working. Do you want to make it an answer for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put `CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"` in the `SqlDataSource` markup like the following.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="IDxxx" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringxxx %>" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table Where @Parameter1 = Table.Column1" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Parameter1" />                                        
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName");
            cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("yourConnString");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("YourParaameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;           

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // or any other command that you want to execute
```

Comment: Although I am sure your solution works, it was not the exact solution I was looking for. CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" in the SqlDataSource markup of ASP.NET works.